Hi , I`m trying to sort this column by days .Is it possible to use ORDERBY before IF statement?
Age Bucket = 
IF(
AND (Aged_Inv[Days Aged] >= 0, Aged_Inv[Days Aged]<= 14), "0-14 Days",
IF(
AND (Aged_Inv[Days Aged] >= 15, Aged_Inv[Days Aged]<= 30), "15-30 Days",
IF(
AND (Aged_Inv[Days Aged] >= 31, Aged_Inv[Days Aged]<= 60), "31-60 Days",
IF(
AND (Aged_Inv[Days Aged] >= 61, Aged_Inv[Days Aged]<= 90), "61-90 Days",
IF(
AND (Aged_Inv[Days Aged] >= 91, Aged_Inv[Days Aged]<= 180), "91-180 Days",
IF(
AND (Aged_Inv[Days Aged] >= 181, Aged_Inv[Days Aged]<= 365), "181-365 Days",
IF(
AND (Aged_Inv[Days Aged] >= 366, Aged_Inv[Days Aged]<= 730), "1-2 Years",
IF(
AND (Aged_Inv[Days Aged] >=731 , Aged_Inv[Days Aged]<=1095 ), "2-3 Years",
IF(
 (Aged_Inv[Days Aged] >= 1096) , "Over 3 Years", "Error"
)))))))))

I`m expecting to see days in a Slicer based on what i did in my code .
